# Getting an odd error while creating angular app with angular CLI

Tags: node.js, angular, git-bash

I've just installed nodejs and angular CLI successfully, but when I tried to create(with ng new, running the git bash with admin privileges) my first(and then second) app I got an error(same error twice: one for each new app):

[Image with the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nr4oN.jpg)

Using windows 10, 64bit

Comment: I think I got it... I think it's because of the Visual Studio. Will test it now

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Ok you are doing it with npm, I had faced the same error. It is due to the privileges in your system. you can run `npm cache clean` and try.

If that still doesnt work I suggest you try it with yarn.